# SQL Server Active Operations dialog Time issue

Tags: time, ssis, sql-server-2016

I have a job that calls an **SSIS package**.  The package was taking WAY longer than usual to complete so I opened the Active Operations dialog box and selected the 'Stop' button and ended it (this is a new server and the first time I have had to stop an Active Operation).  When I went to check the Executions log for the package I noticed that the End time was an hour off.  So I checked the server time and the time returned by `GetDate()` on the `SQL` instance and both of them were correct.  Anyone know where the Active Operations Stop process gets it's time from?   [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value that gets updated as end time is - SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(). You can find this detail in the stored procedure - [catalog].[stop_operation]. Likewise the columns start_time and end_time are from the table - [internal].[operations]. All of these are part of the SSISDB database.

The tables and procedures in this DB are easy to interpret and that's how I have come across. Very much self-explanatory sometimes.

You can find more documentation at this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/views-integration-services-catalog). Having said that, the issue that you are facing is really strange. Seeing EndTime earlier than StartTime.